# How do I acess value return "thenReturn" mokito method

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJqVl.png)

How do I access the return value of the mock? The problem is that testing is not being efficient. The clause that is to be used is veirifcar.

is supposed to return null or not null. This way is not correct because it always returns the object.

```
valor3 = Mockito.when(refinariaProvider.buscarRefinariaPadrao("LUBNOR")).thenAnswer(new Answer(){
            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                return Arrays.toString(args);
            }
        });

        // valor3.getMock()?
```

Comment: I don't understand. You're telling the invocation of `searchClassProviderEx(null)` to return `null`. It will return `null`.

Comment: What is a real problem? What are you going to do? Generally null is null

Comment: When you say that testing is not efficient what do you mean? It's not usually a goal for test code using mocks to be efficient.

Comment: Thanks! look a picture. I need get the return value. This are functional test.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a **Mockito Answer** which can be used to return a different value depending on the *args[]* your *searchClassProviderEx* method is called with.

```
value2 = Mockito.when (classProvider.searchClassProviderEx (anyString())) thenAnswer(new Answer() {
    Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
        Object mock = invocation.getMock();
        return "called with arguments: " + args;
    }
});
//Following prints "called with arguments: hello"
System.out.println(classProvider.searchClassProviderEx("hello"));
```